# React hooks api chained call sometimes gets data sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to make an a chained call to an API to gather data on NBA teams.  The First call is to gather the team names and logo and make cards out of that data.

The second call takes the data from the first call to make another call to get NBA players on certain teams...

The ultimate goal of the project is to have cards of all 30 NBA teams with a button.  When that button is clicked, the players of the clicked team appear below.

My issue is that sometimes I get the data from the API call and sometimes I get an empty array.

```
function Team() {

    const [nbaData, setNbaData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getNBAData = async () => {
            const NBATeams = await axios.get("https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/teams?key=b7f466ebf369487fa904c3d202b049d1");
            const playersData = await Promise.all(NBATeams.data.map(async (res) => {
                const players = await axios.get(`https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/Players/${res.Key}?key=b7f466ebf369487fa904c3d202b049d1`
                );

                return players.data;
            }));

            setNbaData([{ NBATeams: NBATeams , playersData: playersData }])
            console.log(nbaData)
        };

        getNBAData();
        
    },[]);
```

When I mess around and put `nbaData` in the dependence it works to get that data but it's an infinite loop of data... not sure what's going on.

Any ideas why I sometimes get data and sometimes don't?

Thanks!

Comment: can you product a codesandbox demo for this ? would be much easier to debug!

Comment: Looks like the problem is not at that component, because you're setting the second parameter as empty array so that would'nt run twice unless you render the component in other high level.

Comment: Can you post where is used this component?

Comment: Team component is imported to the App.js component and render there

Comment: <iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/hopeful-clarke-k1ej7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="hopeful-clarke-k1ej7"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>